# Why is not downloading any file?

Tags: c#, html, dom, webclient, html-agility-pack

Hey guys I made this little program to scrape some html information but it is not downloading some files...

Here's the code:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                List<string> source = new List<string>();

                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                string url = "http://www.jornaldenegocios.pt/mercados/bolsa/detalhe/wall_street_cada_vez_mais_perto_de_maximo_historico.html";
                HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);

                var head = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
                var meta = head.SelectNodes("//meta").AsEnumerable();
                var link = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head").SelectNodes("//link").AsEnumerable();
                var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                        .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                        .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

                var titulo = "";
                var descricao = "";
                var linkImg = "";
                var linkIcon = "";
                var linkImgAlt = "";
                int length = 0;

                Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
                string host = myUri.Host;


                var fbProperties = (head.SelectNodes("//meta[contains(@property, 'og:')]") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
                    .ToDictionary(n => n.Attributes["property"].Value, n => n.Attributes["content"].Value);


                linkIcon = (head.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@rel, 'apple-touch-icon')]")?.Attributes["href"]?.Value) ??
                    (head.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@rel, 'icon')]")?.Attributes["href"]?.Value) ??
                    host + "/favicon.ico";


                var title = head.SelectSingleNode("//title")?.InnerText;



                if (fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:title", out titulo) == false || titulo == null)
                {
                    titulo = (title ?? host);
                }

                if (fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:description", out descricao) == false || descricao == null)
                {
                    descricao = ("none");
                }

                if (fbProperties.TryGetValue("og:image", out linkImg) == false || linkImg == null)
                {
                    linkImg = (linkImgAlt ?? "none");
                }

                foreach (var node in urls)
                {
                    source.Add(node);
                }

                foreach (var links in source)
                {
                    length = client.DownloadData(links).Length;

                    if (length<client.DownloadData(links).Length)
                    {
                        linkImgAlt = links;
                    }

                }




                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Titulo:");
                Console.WriteLine(titulo);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Descriçao:");
                Console.WriteLine(descricao);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Link da Imagem:");
                Console.WriteLine(linkImg);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Link do Icon:");
                Console.WriteLine(linkIcon);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Link da Imagem:");
                Console.WriteLine(length);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Link da Imagem:");
                Console.WriteLine(linkImgAlt);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every thing is working just fine just this little part is giving me some problems :

```
foreach (var node in urls)
{
    source.Add(node);
}

foreach (var links in source)
{            
    length = client.DownloadData(links).Length;

    if (length<client.DownloadData(links).Length)
    {
        linkImgAlt = links;
    }
}
```

Here is the Error I get by running the program :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\i\closePestana.png'.

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXuO.png

I think this is not downloading the files and that's why is giving me this error message.
Could you help me fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is this meant to do: `length = client.DownloadData(links).Length; if (length<client.DownloadData(links).Length)`

Comment: You may need `file://` on the front of that uri...

Comment: I wanted to select the biggest image on the site if there wasn't an "og:image".